# Advantages/disadvantages to user registration and login methods

Tags: authentication, registration, user-registration

Take the following three user registration/login methods (or add your own):

- with OpenID
- with Email Address + Password (not OpenID)
- with Username + Password

What are the advantages and disadvantages to each for a general internet audience (i.e., not a super tech-savvy audience of Stack Overflow)?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like homework.  Is it?  If so, please use the [homework] tag.

Comment: Hi @S.Lott, I'm not a student. Just a noob who thought this was the best way to phrase my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accept a both login by email address and by username. A user may forget one but not the other.

As for OpenID--- nobody's gonna have a clue what that means. But you could say "log in with your Google Account" - but the word OpenID should not be mentioned in any significant way.

Also, some people are gonna think you are asking for all their Google Account information. That is what I thought at first with Stack Overflow. And I thought I was tech savvy!

Answer (score 2):

One of the core advantages of OpenID is that your site does not end up storing user credentials itself because the authentication is done at the 3rd party OpenID providers server and your site is sent an authentication token.

Another semi-related plus is that you can also request other information related to the authenticating user that the provider may have. This can help to streamline the registration process further because you can get basic profile information like a first name, last name and email address which the user would otherwise be asked to provide.

OpenID works by shifting responsibility for authentication from your site to a remote third party. Because you are dependent upon that third party to authenticate your users for you, if that party is unavailable, then those users whose identity information is stored with that party will not be able to authenticate to your site if their OpenID is their only means of authentication.

Further to the previous point, because a given OpenID may represent a valid identity at many websites, a compromised OpenID is potentially more valuable to an attacker than a set of site-specific credentials. As a consumer of OpenID your site can't do much about this, but its worth being aware of nonetheless

As a user, I like OpenID because:

- I dont have to think up another set of credentials that I have to remember-
- I feel better about registering because there are less form fileds to fill in (if you get my reg data from the provider)-
- I feel better because I don't have to trust your website with my credentials because they are stored at the server of an organisation I already trust and know to have a bigger budget for security than your tiny little website

Comment: Ah crap. missed the general internet audience bit.

Answer (score 0):

> for a general internet audience

This is all mumbo-jumbo.

Ask your mother (or grandmother).  It's all just confusing and silly.

No one can remember this junk.  I can't tell them apart -- as a user.  As an implementer, I prefer email addresses because the `@domain` business assures uniqueness without any pain to the user.

As a user, I rely on MacOS Keychain and 1Password to keep it all square for me.